# "this"-keyword for a jQuery object

Tags: jquery, prototype, this, keyword

what does the "this-keyword" reference to in this context:

```
jQuery.fn.m=function (){
  console.log(this == $("#diveins")); // gives a false what does it reference to?
};

$("#diveins").m();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a jQuery method, `this` is the jQuery collection that you called the method on. So in your example, it's the collection returned by `$("#diveins")`.

The reason you get `false` is because every time you call `$("#diveins")` you get a new collection. If you wrote:

```
console.log($("#diveins") == $("#diveins"));
```

it will also show `false`.

You can use `this.is("#diveins")`. This will work if you're just looking for a single element -- there doesn't seem to be an easy way to compare jQuery collections.

```js
jQuery.fn.m=function (){
  console.log(this.is("#diveins"));
};

$("#diveins").m();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="diveins"></div>
```